# Get Slot path from url in Google publisher tag

Tags: url, slots

I am working on google publisher tag.Is there any way to get slot path from url

•   Slot Path: /1111/abc.com.au/xx/xxx

> > Any way to get the value of x's from the url.
> >
> > > Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) to access the URL parameters.